# Server 2008 R2 configuring network broadcast with multiple interfaces

Tags: networking, routes, windows-server-2008-r2, broadcast

I have a virtual machine with Server 2008 R2 within a customer environment. It has two network interfaces which are both wired virtual ethernet adapters. One interface connects to the corporate network, internet, etc. The second adapter connects to a specific closed VLAN.

The corporate network adapter is setup with a default gateway and DNS - fine, I need this to RDP to the machine and access the internet/domain controller. The second network adapter on the closed VLAN has an IP / subnet but no default gateway / DNS - again this is fine, I understand I cannot have multiple gateways.

I have setup static routes so I can access equipment on the closed VLAN - great! However broadcast packets do not appear to be routing correctly as I am not receiving any traffic after sending broadcast messages on the closed VLAN. I am not sure my routing is correct and would appreciate some feedback to get this working. I am not a networking professional but have some knowledge in this area. My main issue is I do not understand enough about Metric and I think I may need to add another static route for 192.168.11.255 (broadcast) but I do not know how to structure this route. I use the 'route add' command in windows cmd.

Big thanks for anyone who can take the time to assist

IP Details:

```
    Interface 1 (corporate network): IP 10.43.11.145
    Mask 255.255.255.128
    GW 10.43.11.129
    DNS 10.40.144.13, 10.40.144.14

    Interface 2 (closed VLAN):
    IP 192.168.10.159
    Mask 255.255.252.0
    GW (blank)
    DNS (blank)
```

Static Route Details

```
    Static Routes

    Interface List
    18...00 50 56 be 7f dc..... vmxnet3 Ethernet Adapter
    12...00 50 56 be 72 91..... vmxnet3 Ethernet Adapter #5
     1......................... Sofware Loopback Interface 1

    IPV4 Route Table
    =========
    Active Routes:
    Network Destinations    Netmask     Gateway     Interface   Metric
    0.0.0.0             0.0.0.0         10.43.11.129 10.43.11.145   261
    10.43.11.128        255.255.255.128 On-Link     10.43.11.145    261
    10.43.11.145        255.255.255.255 On-Link     10.43.11.145    261
    10.43.11.255        255.255.255.255 On-Link     10.43.11.145    261
    127.0.0.0           255.0.0.0       On-Link     127.0.0.1       306
    127.0.0.1           255.0.0.0       On-Link     127.0.0.1       306
    127.255.255.255     255.255.255.255 On-Link     127.0.0.1       306
    192.168.8.0         255.255.252.0   192.168.8.1 192.168.10.159  265
    192.168.10.159      255.255.255.255 192.168.8.1 192.168.10.159  266
    244.0.0.0           240.0.0.0       On-Link     127.0.0.1       306
    244.0.0.0           240.0.0.0       On-Link     10.43.11.145    261
    244.0.0.0           240.0.0.0       On-Link     192.168.10.159  261
    255.255.255.255     255.255.255.255 On-Link     127.0.0.1       306
    255.255.255.255     255.255.255.255 On-Link     10.43.11.145    261
    255.255.255.255     255.255.255.255 On-Link     192.168.10.159  261
    =========
    Persistent Routes:
    Network Address     Netmask     Gateway         Metric
    0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         10.43.11.129    Default
    192.168.8.0     255.255.252.0   192.168.8.1     260
    192.168.10.159  255.255.255.255 192.168.8.1     261
    =========

    IPv6 Route Table
    =========
    Active Routes:
    If  Metric  Network Destination Gateway
    1   306 ::1/128         On-Link
    1   306 ff00::/8        On-Link
    =========
    Presistant Routes:
    None
```

Answer (score 0):

2 machine machine A 10.1.1.1/24 machine b 20.1.1.1/24 for making route between that two machine
in machine A i have 2 nic i should realize that interface id for that you should go to ncpa.cpl console open every nic and see id that id used in route command 
first in vmware you should make vlan and all machines should be in same vlan for understand broadcasting
second in machine A use route command for send packet to machine B

```
route add 20.1.1.0 mask 255.255.255.0 10.1.1.1 if 1
```

in machine B we should route add for return route

```
route add 10.1.1.0 mask 255.255.255.0 20.1.1.1 if 1
```

for last test you should ping from two machine
if request time out message that's for firewall
if destination host unreachable you receive that for mistake routing